# How can I check that the user is inputing a double?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get the user to give me a diameter in a number format and if they type in a string, the program does not crash. This code tells me if the input was an integer or not, but it only works after you type an answer in twice. How do I make it so that it tells me if the first user input is an integer or not?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(true) {

            System.out.print("What is the diameter: ");
                try {
                    double diameter = input.nextDouble();
                    break;
                }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
                }
            }
        input.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: First you say you want to verify that the user input was a double, and then you say it should be an integer.  You've gotta pick one, it can't be both.  For doubles, see [`Double#parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)).  For integers, see[`Integer#parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what problem are you facing.

Comment: @Charlie_Armstrong ah sorry about that, it should be double.

Comment: @AKSingh im just trying to see if there is a way to make sure the user is inputting a double without generating errors on the console. Just kinda repeatedly asking the user to type in another input if their first one was invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just prompt for a double to start with?  For something like dimensions of an object, taking in all doubles would be appropriate. If you want to prompt for strings, take input with `input.next()`.  You can still catch exceptions.

```
double diameter;
while (true) {
    System.out.print(
            "What is the diameter of the sphere (cm): ");
    try {
        diameter = input.nextDouble();
        break;  // get out of the loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException mme) {
        System.out.println("double value not entered");
        // clear the scanner input
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
System.out.println("The diameter is " + diameter);
```

Comment: I suggest both of you should edit your answers so that your fans may get a second chance . @aran - Why did you delete your correct answer?

Comment: sorry, im a pretty new coder. When you say catch exceptions, do you mean using try catch?

Comment: Yes the catch block catches thrown exceptions of the type(s) specified so the programmer can take action to handle them.  Sometimes it's as simple as just informing the user and reprompting for input.  In this case a String input would cause the exception.

Comment: Ok so i was trying to use the catch block and it works, but i want it to repeat the question until the user gives a valid answer. So i put a while loop around the try catch and when i entered an invalid input, it asked the question "what is the diameter" infinitely

Comment: @L0k3d20uz4 My apologies.  Try the updated answer.  I put in some comments to explain what I did.  I also put the entire code in a while loop.  The break is used to exit it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to see if the item is a double (and not an integer), one way to do it is to read the input as a double using `nextDouble()` and catching `InputMismatchException` in case it isn't. And with a while loop you can repeatedly ask the user to enter a value until a valid double is entered.

```
Double diameter = null;
while (diameter == null) {
    try {
        diameter = input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("Input was invalid. Try again: ");
        input.next(); // skip the invalid input
    }
}
System.out.print(diameter);
```

Comment: I tried this method but it repeats the question repeated

Comment: sorry it repeats "What is the diameter of the sphere (cm): " infinitely

Comment: Not possible unless you put that line in your loop.

Comment: Yes i did put that line in my loop because i want that question to be repeated to the user again until they put in a number

Comment: I would have to see your code to know what’s wrong with it.